# Creating Lead Shares

Tags: apex, trigger, leads

I have a requirement to where I need create a `LeadShare` with my PowerPartners.  So if a Lead is created by a PowerPartner then it will placed into `LeadShare`.  My Orignal thinking was to take the User object and find all of the User Ids that are type "PowerPartners", then once I find all of them I will go into my `GroupMembers` and I will find said Users. Then from there assignments will be made stuff in `LeadShare` will be set. Is my logic correct?  Trigger will be below..

Also I can't do this type of loop on User Object.  So I need logic help

```
trigger PartnerLeadShare on Lead (after insert,after update) {

 if(Trigger.isAfter){
 List<LeadShare> leadShareList = new list<LeadShare>();   
Set<id>pUserMap=new set<id>();  
  for(User u: [select id,UserType,isActive from user where UserType = 'PowerPartner'  and IsActive = True]){       
           {
            pUserMap.add(u.id);  
            System.debug('pUserMap ' +pUserMap);
    }
  }
Map<Id, GroupMember> groupMap = new Map <Id, GroupMember>();
for(GroupMember grp : [select GroupId, UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where   UserORGroupID IN:pUserMap]){
groupMap.put(grp.UserOrGroupId, grp);
}
System.debug('groupList    '+groupMap ); 
 if(pUserMap != null){
//System.debug('Inside PartUserMap != null');
for(Lead ld: trigger.new){  
    System.debug('Created BY!!  ' +ld.CreatedById);  
     if(groupMap.containsKey(ld.CreatedById)){    
            System.debug('Inside GroupMap Contains');          
            LeadShare ldShare = new LeadShare (LeadId = ld.id, LeadAccessLevel =   'Edit');   
            leadShareList.add(ldShare ); 
        }       
} 
}
```

Comment: Btw, you probably need an **insert leadShareList;** at the end.

Comment: I am I just cut that code off because I'm still trying to get a comparison.  I'm starting a new thread in hope I can help for my test class

Comment: Did you manage to get where you wanted with this in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a trigger on Lead (which is what you're using), Trigger.new only contains the list of Lead objects that has been inserted/updated/deleted/undeleted (depending on context), which is why you cannot iterate over it as a collection of User objects.

You can however build your own list of user IDs and then use that to get the User objects you require:

```
Set<ID> userIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Lead aLead : Trigger.new)
{
    userIds.add(aLead.CreatedById);
}

Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>
([
    SELECT 
        Id
    FROM 
        User 
    WHERE 
        Id IN :userIds 
        AND UserType = 'PowerPartner' 
        AND IsActive = true
]);

Set<Id> userIds = userMap.keySet();
```

Comment: Hey Alex, that gives me an error "Illegal assignment from List<User> to List<id>"

Comment: @EricSSH Sorry about that, I've fixed that issue now.