# Community User - Access to records

Tags: customer-portal, partner-portal

We are in the process of migrating our Portal to a Partner Community.  Building a replica of what is in our Portal.  We want to give our Distributors access to Leads that they have generated.  Problem is, they are not the owner of the lead.  They generate the leads via a Web-to-Lead form and that is assigned to an internal owner based on the State that the lead is located.  There is a field on the Lead that lists the Distributors Account Name.

How do I create a list view that gives access to a Partner Community license user of Leads they have created but don't own?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can do this.

1. Using [**Queues**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_queues.htm&type=5). Create Queues respective to Distributor Account and assign the Partner Users on that Account to the Queue. Using assignment rules, just assign the Lead to the Queue, so that the members of the Queue get access to the Lead records. This way you will also get the Queue List View available to your Users.
2. Using [**Groups**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_groups.htm&type=5). Create Public Groups respective to Distributor Account and assign the Partner Users to that Group. Then using a [criteria based sharing rule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm), share the Lead records to that Group thus providing access to the Users. Users in any List View will be able to view only those records to which they have access to.
3. Using [**Apex Managed Sharing**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm). This will be a customization route, where you will need to share the Lead records to respective Users or a Group based on certain criteria as soon as the Lead records are created.

You can find more details on the approaches on their respective links. Also take a look at [Share CRM Data with Your Partners](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_share_crm_data) trailhead which should provide you with some related details.

Comment: (3) is technically Apex-based Manual Sharing, since it's with a standard object and full-fledged Apex Managed Sharing is not available. Not to be picky, it's just more complex to implement on a standard object.

Comment: `LeadShare` can be still utilized, isn't it? I would though agree that it's a bit more complex and I opt to solve such use cases with as much as it can be using config options as long as those can be managed.

Comment: Yes, `LeadShare` can still be utilized, but you cannot use custom RowCause entries, and share records don't survive ownership changes because they're all RowCause == Manual. They can also be manipulated by users. Code has to be more defensive!

Comment: Get it now, yes that's true. I was thinking the share object itself cannot be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create record of LeadShare for each partner user with whomever you want to share the record.

A similar conversation is here: [Creating Lead Shares](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33638/creating-lead-shares)